# Android Studio error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Tags: android, array, listview, bucle-for

estoy teniendo un problema que llevo horas y no puedo solucionar. El error que me da al compilar el programa es el del título.

Esta es mi clase:

```
public class ElegirCuidados extends AppCompatActivity {

private String elegirCuidados;
String[] miArray = {};
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
ListView lvDias;
String dia = "6";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.elegir_cuidados);

    miArray = new String[]{dia};
    lvDias = findViewById(R.id.lvDias);

    for(int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(dia); i++){
        miArray[i] = ("Día "+ i);
    }

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, miArray);
    lvDias.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

}

Este es el Logcat:

> 11-14 12:30:09.936 15663-15663/com.example.rodrigo.petshotel E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.rodrigo.petshotel, PID: 15663
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rodrigo.petshotel/com.example.rodrigo.petshotel.ElegirCuidados}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2678)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
>           at com.example.rodrigo.petshotel.ElegirCuidados.onCreate(ElegirCuidados.java:31)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6687)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2631)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)

La verdad no entiendo donde puede estar el error, intenté de todo ya. Me podrían ayudar?

El resultado de esto sería mostrar en la ListView estos elementos:
Día 1
Día 2
Día 3
Día 4
Día 5
Día 6

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas tratando de leer un segundo elemento de tu array (index=1, recuerda que inicia desde 0), cuando tu array únicamente contiene un elemento (length=1)

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Te sugiero definir como limite maximo en tu bucle la longitud del array (`i < miArray.length`) :

```
//   for(int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(dia); i++){
   for(int i = 0; i < miArray.length; i++){
        miArray[i] = ("Día "+ i);
    }
```

De esta forma solo introducirás valores a tu array dependiendo de su longitud.

---

Para que se muestren los 6 elementos que deseas desplegar en tu Adapter, debes agregar 6 elementos al array:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.elegir_cuidados);

    //*Agrega elementos a array
    miArray = new String[]{"1","2","3","4","5","6"};

    lvDias = findViewById(R.id.lvDias);

    //for(int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(dia); i++){
    for(int i = 0; i < miArray.length; i++){
        miArray[i] = ("Día "+ i);
    }

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, miArray);
    lvDias.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Lo hice de esa manera y el ListView sólo me muestra un resultado, es decir "Dia 1", no me muestra los demas. Que podrá ser?

Comment: @Rodrigo tu array al parecer solo contiene un elemento. Estas definiendo :  miArray = new String[]{dia}; y día tiene el valor de dia = "6"; en realidad solo tienes un elemento. Revisa la actualización de la respuesta.

Comment: Solucionado, resulta que el length de miarray me estaba trayendo solo 1 posición por algún motivo, el tema es que estaba mal declarado el array. Lo corregí y primero logré que el length sea 6, y luego cuando probé el codigo completo ya me armó el ListView como yo lo necesito. Muchas gracias

Comment: Estaba definiendo solo un elemento: miArray = new String[]{dia}; , si esta  respuesta ayudo a solucionar la problematica puedes marcarla como solución, revisa [tour].